# Group by clause is taking more time for executing in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, query-performance

I have a select query with group by clause. When I execute this query it is taking more time to execute. . Without using aggregate functions and group by clause I am getting the result very fast. If I use group by clause and aggregate functions then it takes time. Is there any way to improve the performance for the below query?

```
SELECT a.unit_class_su class_type,
    a.unit_type_su class_unit_type,
    a.unit_code_su class_unit_code,
    a.item_no,
    a.item_type,
    b.item_name_official item_name_global,
    NULL in_stock_range_code,
    NULL in_cust_ord_range_code,
    NULL valid_from_dtime,
    NULL valid_to_dtime,
    MIN (a.iu_date) upd_dtime,
    MIN (a.ii_date) ins_dtime,
    NULL del_dtime
  FROM scpixcem01.cox_cem_relation_t a,
    crccem01.cox_item_v2_t b
  WHERE a.su_relation_status = 'COMMITTED'
  AND a.item_no              = b.item_no
  AND a.item_type            = b.item_type
  AND a.unit_code_su NOT    IN (SELECT BU_CODE FROM COX.COX_STORES_T WHERE IS_HOME_SHOPPING_STORE = 'YES' AND DELETE_DTIME IS NULL)
  GROUP BY a.unit_class_su,
    a.unit_type_su,
    a.unit_code_su,
    a.item_no,
    a.item_type,
    b.item_name_official
```

Comment: Without the `group by`, are you fetching all of the rows or just the first screenful?

Comment: In query if I don't use aggregate functions MIN (a.iu_date) upd_dtime,
 MIN (a.ii_date) ins_dtime and group by clauses the response is very fast.

Comment: Sometimes the *first screenful* of rows is returned very fast because Oracle doesn't need to read all of the rows, but fetching *all* of the data takes much longer. In order to aggregate, it has to read all of the data.

Comment: I am able to fetch all the records without group by clause  and aggregate functions MIN (a.iu_date) upd_dtime, MIN (a.ii_date) ins_dtime.  is there any way to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: There is no tuning technique specifically for aggregation, no. Perhaps if you posted some details such as the two execution plans, someone might spot something.

Comment: You could try creating indexes if this is a query you need to run a lot. A clustered index on all the group by columns might help.